# Tab Bar corner radius not showing transparent corners

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, swift5

I'm trying to add a corner radius to my Tab Bar in the top left and top right corners.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class TabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tabBar.layer.cornerRadius = 32
        self.tabBar.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.tabBar.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
    }

}
```

And here is my Interface Builder for the Tab Bar:

[image]

But my Tab Bar comes out looking like this:

[image]

As you can see, if you look at the corners, they're not transparent, they're white. It should show the image behind it. So it looks like something is going wrong with masking, but I'm not sure what.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my other IBDesignable class that might be affecting this:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class DesignableView: UIView {

}

@IBDesignable
class DesignableButton: UIButton {

}

@IBDesignable
class DesignableLabel: UILabel {

}

@IBDesignable
class DesignableTextField: UITextField {

}

extension UIView {

    @IBInspectable
    var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
            layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var shadowOffset: CGSize {
        get {
            return layer.shadowOffset
        }
        set {
            layer.shadowOffset = newValue
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var shadowColor: UIColor {
        get {
            return UIColor(cgColor: layer.shadowColor!)
        }
        set {
            layer.shadowColor = newValue.cgColor
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var shadowRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.shadowRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.shadowRadius = newValue
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var shadowOpacity: Float {
        get {
            return layer.shadowOpacity
        }
        set {
            layer.shadowOpacity = newValue
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var borderWidth: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.borderWidth
        }
        set {
            layer.borderWidth = newValue
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var borderColor: UIColor {
        get {
            return UIColor(cgColor: layer.borderColor!)
        }
        set {
            layer.borderColor = newValue.cgColor
        }
    }

}
```

Update:

I've found that if I change the background color of the View Controller behind the tabs, the corners of the tab bar match that color:

[image]

If I debug the view, you can actually see the little red corners in one of the views:

[image]

What does this mean?

Comment: @matt What values for clipsToBounds and masksToBounds should I be setting for the corners to work?

Comment: @matt I added my other IBDesignable class

Comment: It might be the background image constraint  issue. Set bg color to view and check the result

Comment: I updated the question with some findings, cc: @matt

Answer (score 2):

I created a project with just the TabBarController. In that, I used your code and set the corner radius, border width and border color.

In the first ViewController, I did the following:

1. Checked to see if "Under Bottom Bars" is checked in the ViewController.
2. Added an image and extended it to go under the bottom bar.

It all seemed to work as expected. See image below. May be you can double check your code to see if any of the above steps help.

[image: Tab bar]

Comment: Unfortunately, I checked your steps and compared them to mine, and it still doesn't work :/

Comment: Create a separate project and try my steps. It should help isolate the issue.

Comment: I tried the same code as above and it works for me. My Xcode version is 11.3 (11C29)

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Based on the recent layout posted in the question. There seems to be a layer that stops the rounded corners from being displayed. can't reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this same issue, I was anchoring my `UICollectionView` to `view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor`. This caused me to see the view controllers background color behind the `UITabBarController` instead of the cells content. From your view hierarchy it looks like the same issue, the white frame is not going behind the `UITabBarController`. Setting the `UICollectionView` bottom anchor to `view.bottomAnchor` and adding a bottom content inset to the collection view fixed my issue

Here is the code i'm using in my `UITabBarController` subclass https://stackoverflow.com/a/65285566/19499376