# Managing Custom UITabBar View

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

Following this [repo](https://github.com/mohammed-abuamra/custom-tabbarcontroller), I created a custom "tabBar" via a separate `uiview` that sits behind the native `uitabbarcontroller` tabBar. The custom tabBar has rounded corners and a shadow.

Everything works great except in the instances I push/pop a new `uiviewcontroller` onto/from the embedded `uinavigationcontroller` stack, where I hide the tabBar.

My issue is smoothly toggling the custom tabBar to hide/show during these instances.

I've set `.isHidden = true/false` for the custom tabBar when a `uiviewcontroller` is pushed/popped, and either the custom tabBar disappears too early or appears too late relative to the native `uitabbarcontroller` tabBar.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController {

let customTabBarView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView(frame: .zero)
    
    view.backgroundColor = Constants.style.offWhite
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    view.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
    view.clipsToBounds = true
    
    view.layer.masksToBounds = false
    view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: -8.0)
    view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.12
    view.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0
    
    return view
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    self.tabBar.isHidden = true
    self.tabBar.backgroundColor = .clear
    self.tabBar.barStyle = .default
    self.tabBar.isTranslucent = true
    
    addCustomTabBarView()
    hideTabBarBorder()
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    customTabBarView.frame = tabBar.frame
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    var newSafeArea = UIEdgeInsets()
    
    newSafeArea.bottom += customTabBarView.bounds.size.height
    self.children.forEach({$0.additionalSafeAreaInsets = newSafeArea})
}

//Function invoked when pushing/popping viewControllers onto/from the embedded navigation stack
func toggleCustomTabBarView(shouldHide: Bool) {
    self.customTabBarView.isHidden = shouldHide
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        UIView.transition(with: self.view, duration: TimeInterval(UINavigationController.hideShowBarDuration), options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
        })
    }
}
        
func addCustomTabBarView() {
    customTabBarView.frame = tabBar.frame
    view.addSubview(customTabBarView)
    view.bringSubviewToFront(self.tabBar)
}

func hideTabBarBorder() {
    let tabBar = self.tabBar
    tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage.from(color: .clear)
    tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    tabBar.clipsToBounds = true
}
}

extension UIImage {
    static func from(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context!.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        context!.fill(rect)
        let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return img!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65285566/9466631

Couldn't find anything as a solve for the dummy view behind the tabBar, but this new solution worked for me that avoids using the dummy view altogether and adds a CAShapeLayer instead.